# Windows 7 rotates screen when accessing Google and other search engines

Tags: windows-7, display, google-search

I have a laptop with Windows 7. When I access Google and search anything the screen always rotates 90 degrees. This happens with any browser — Chrome, Internet Explorer or Firefox — when I press some keys, tried remote and worked smoothly.

Created a new user profile, and same issue.

I checked the display settings, and it’s set correctly to horizontal.

I checked display drivers and display program settings (Unchecked “Shortcut Keys” and “Rotate Monitor”).

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean the screen "rotates"? Is it 90 or 180 degrees or constant? Please add some more details like what make and model of laptop, if it is touch screen, if it happens in all browsers, etc.

Comment: 90 degrees constant

Comment: Are you going to give us any more details? It will be difficult to help you without details.

Comment: Which details would you need?

Comment: I added what i checked

Comment: It's only when i use some browser and use any search engine, commonly google

Comment: What browsers exactly?

Comment: All of them, IE, Chrome, firefox

Comment: This is very strange.  Is it the entire screen that rotates (including the browser), or is it just the page inside the browser that rotates?  Can you send a picture?